# TinyMCE integration in StencilJS application

Tags: tinymce, stenciljs, tinymce-6

I am working on StencilJS and want to integrate tinyMCE in my stencilJS application. I dont find any documentation of integrating tinyMCE in stencilJS. Can you please help?

i tried installing tinymce 6 through npm in my StencilJS application and initialize the tinymce in connectedCallback() of StencilJS Component, and in return used a textarea and call that textarea in tinymce.init but somehow it is not working. Also , not sure where to use api-Key of tinymce in this?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/webcomponent/

Comment: yes, I tried this . I am able to load tinymce-editor but I am not able to set or get the content value from editor (even after using the methods from documentation)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman  I was able to integrate  tinymce-editor in StencilJS component. Its different from the way web component is done. Its need to be initialized in StencilJS componentDidLoad LifeCycle Method and in return   <textarea id="my-tinymce-component"></textarea> has to be used, this textarea need to be replaced with tinymce editor in initialization